# No border dropdownmenu

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a dropdown menu, there are no border

I have tried to change the words myself but without success someone would like to help me with this.It's probably a small thing, but I'm just starting to program a website so I don't know much about it yet. without this I can't go on with my website so if someone is so nice to help me this would be great!

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  background: #171c24;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
nav .content .links {
  margin-left: 80px;
  display: flex;
}
.content .logo a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.content .links li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 70px;
}
.content .links li a,
.content .links li label {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 9px 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.content .links li label {
  display: none;
}
.content .links li a:hover,
.content .links li label:hover {
  background: #323c4e;
}
.wrapper .search-icon,
.wrapper .menu-icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper .menu-icon {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper #show-search:checked ~ .search-icon i::before {
  content: "\f00d";
}

.wrapper .search-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper #show-search:checked ~ .search-box {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.search-box input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #171c24;
  padding: 0 100px 0 15px;
}
.search-box input::placeholder {
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
.search-box .go-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  background: #171c24;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.content .links ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #171c24;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.content .links li:hover > ul {
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.content .links ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.content .links ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(-100% + 8px);
}
.content .links ul li {
  position: relative;
}
.content .links ul li:hover ul {
  top: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
  .wrapper nav {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  nav .content .links {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .content .links li a {
    padding: 8px 13px;
  }
  .wrapper .search-box {
    max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  .wrapper .search-box input {
    padding: 0 100px 0 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .wrapper .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .wrapper #show-menu:checked ~ .menu-icon i::before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav .content .links {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    background: #14181f;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: 350px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  nav #show-menu:checked ~ .content .links {
    left: 0%;
  }
  .content .links li {
    margin: 15px 20px;
  }
  .content .links li a,
  .content .links li label {
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .content .links li a.desktop-link {
    display: none;
  }

  .content .links ul,
  .content .links ul ul {
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    background: none;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .content .links #show-features:checked ~ ul,
  .content .links #show-services:checked ~ ul,
  .content .links #show-items:checked ~ ul {
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
  .content .links ul li {
    margin: 7px 20px;
  }
  .content .links ul li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-search">
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu">
    <label for="show-menu" class="menu-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="logo"><a href="Home.html">GameRelease</a></div>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="latest games.html">Latest games</a></li
          <li><a href="#"></a> </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="desktop-link">The recommended games</a>
          <input type="checkbox" id="show-features">
          <label for="show-features">Features</label>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Metal Gear V.Html">Metal Gear V</a></li>
            <li><a href="WRC9.html">WRC9</a></li>
            <li><a href="forzamotorsport7.html">Forza Motorsport 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </form>
  </nav>  
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see a dropdown menu in your snippet demo.

Comment: That is weird. if  I put it in Visiustudio code it work

Comment: I tried fixing up your snippet. It had extra and missing stuff. See if you can get it to work so we can see the problem.

Comment: the first style has no style name.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer will border your dropdown menu

NOTE: Your CSS code is a mess :). It crashes my code. To use my code you will need to please save a copy of your css file for back up. Then delete everything in your css file. Then paste my css code below into the empty css file. Do the same for html file.

If my answer helpful for you, please green tick it to accept this answer and upvote it so other people with same problem will see it and get help too.

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
  
li {
    box-shadow: 2px #cccccc;
    border: 1px ridge black;
    /*width: 300px;*/
}

#ul-outer li{
    width: 300px;
}

#ul-inner li{
    width: 259px;
}
```

Then replace your HTML code with below code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav role="navigation">
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-search">
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu">
      <label for="show-menu" class="menu-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
      <div class="content">
      <div class="logo"><a href="Home.html">GameRelease</a></div>
        <ul class="links" id="ul-outer">
          <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="latest games.html">Latest games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"></a> </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="desktop-link">The recommended games</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-features">
            <label for="show-features">Features</label>
            <ul id="ul-inner">
              <li><a href="Metal Gear V.Html">Metal Gear V</a></li>
              <li><a href="WRC9.html">WRC9</a></li>
              <li><a href="forzamotorsport7.html">Forza Motorsport 7</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </form>
    </nav>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Tim,

For demonstration how the code output looks like, here is Codepen link https://codepen.io/todayUserName/pen/xxgZVBB 

Cheers

Comment: How do you go with it? Did my answer help to work it out yet?